# PHP Printing to continuousPaper Printer

Tags: php, css, printing

I need to print to a printer which will have a fixed width but varying length(continuous roll) depending on the content. I have made my page settings in css making it the exact size I need (the width). My problem is that when printing it prints the part I want and then the roll just keeps coming out until ejecting. I have found that it is a problem of the paper size set in chrome and from what I have read there is no way to modifying it. My question is how can I overcome this problem?

The printer is connected to the pc running the software via USB (or wirelessly at times) but it will always be connected directly to the client. I guess I should make a .net listener app that I can somehow conenct to for printing but it still seems a bit slower in processing. What are my other choices?

Answer (score 0):

please supply a preview of the html and css. Have you tried setting a max-height or height:100%; ?

Comment: That's not the problem. The printing is continous and chrome sets the paper size to 3m (default paper size it chooses from windows).